# How to Install ubuntu with windows 8?

Tags: installation

I am using windows 8.I wanted to install ubuntu alongside with windows. I can install with windows 7 but not windows 8..Please Guide me

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Create a USB Installer using LinuxLive USB Creator. Then, boot from the USB and install Ubuntu in another hard drive, or alongside Windows 8. To install it alongside Windows 8, use GParted, which can be found by clicking Dash which is in the top left and searching for the program. You must partition your drive and use the free space that you have created to install Ubuntu on.

http://www.linuxliveusb.com/

I also found a link that may help you:

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/

Comment: Thanks!! I have installed it by the way that you mentioned..